# Does a cycle (in Simple Harmonic Motion) have to equal 2π?

Tags: waves, terminology, harmonic-oscillator, geometry, definition

So, I search for the definition of [cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_%28geometry%29) and I get this in Wikipedia:

> A turn is a unit of angle measurement equal to 360° or ***2π radians*** (or ...). A turn is also referred to as a revolution or complete rotation or full circle or ***cycle*** or rev or rot.

When I look for motion in [pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum), I get:-

> The time for ***one complete cycle***, ***a left swing and a right swing***, is called the period.

So, in the first quote, it says that one cycle has to be 2π radians, ***but*** in the second quote it says "one complete cycle" is "a left swing and a right swing" (i.e the full cycle doesn't have to be equal to "2π radians").

Can you please clarify what I see as contradicting statements?

Answer (score 4):

The $2\pi$ refers to the *phase angle* ($\phi $), whereas in a pendulum, we have an additional, physical  angle (angle of inclination $\theta$). In a pendulum of small oscillations of maximum angle of inclination $\theta_0$, the two are related by $\theta=\theta_0\sin\phi$. Note that $\phi=\phi_0+\omega t$ is a time-dependent quantity.

Simply put, this phase angle denotes the state of a periodic system in one variable. The system repeats every time $\phi$ increments by $2\pi$.
An angle is used because simple harmonic oscillators are sinusoidal and can be represented on a circle. In this imaginary circle, one 'turn' is $2\pi$ change in $\phi$. It is simultaneously a cycle in the pendulum.

Remember that definitions die when taken out of context ;)

Comment: Something is wrong with your LaTeX formatting.

Comment: Fixed;thanks. For some reason the edit button had gone missing. After bruteforcing the link from the system, the errant $ seemed to be in place. Software glitch?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to write $\theta = \theta_0\cos\phi$ instead of $\theta = \theta$?

Comment: Aah there was a percentage sign in mathjax as well.

Answer (score 1):

The two quoted definitions are both right but they apply to different contexts.

A general definition of a "cycle" is the minimal time after which the system returns to the same configuration. For a rotating object (e.g., a pendulum turning in one direction only) , the cycle is a full turn. For an oscillating pendulum, the cycle is a single "there-and-back" tour.

Answer (score 0):

The way you interpreted the "cycle" is wrong.
One cycle need not to be 2π radians physically. We just REPRESENT an cycle or a periodic motion as if we are varying the angle in a circle and measuring the quantities like time period and frequency etc. As you know if we vary an angle θ to θ+2π then also the value repeats.